# Sorting method producing different output in Python Array versus Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I have some code further below which is doing a merge sort.
It was implemented using a python Array of ints (list of ints) as my initial test case. This went well.
However, once this was working, I generated a random set of numbers to test further. This list is a numpy array.
The merge sort does not work with the numpy array, the results look like repeated figures and like the reconstruction isn't working as intended.

My assumption is that the way the subdivided array is passed to mergesort and then recombined in memory is different between the two, and that is what is causing the issue. However, I am not certain.

Any thoughts?

example arrays:
working with:

```
Array = [48,44,19,59,72,80,42,65,82,8,95,68]
```

not working with

```
unsorted = np.random.randint(1, 1000, 150)
```

The merge sort code:

```
#function for merging two sub-arrays
def merge(left, right, Array):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0

    while (i < len(left) and j < len(right)):
        if (left[i] < right[j]):
            Array[k] = left[i]
            i = i+1
        else:
            Array[k] = right[j]
            j = j+1

        k = k+1

    while (i < len(left)):
        Array[k] = left[i]
        i = i+1
        k = k+1

    while (j < len(right)):
        Array[k] = right[j]
        j = j+1
        k = k+1
 
#function for dividing and calling merge function
def mergesort(Array):
    n = len(Array)
    if (n < 2):
        return

    mid = n / 2
    
    left = Array[0 : int(np.round(mid))]
    right  = Array[int(np.round(mid)) : n]
    print("array size = {}, leftsize= {}, rightsize= {}".format(n, len(left), len(right)))

    mergesort(left)
    mergesort(right)

    merge(left, right, Array)
    
    return Array
```

Then just need to call the following to compare the output:

```
mergesort(Array)
mergesort(unsorted)
```

Comment: Have you tried with `mid = n // 2` i/o `int(np.round(mid))`?

Comment: Interestingly your `unsorted` is an `array` while `Array` is a `list`.

Comment: Hi,

This is a good workaround for the rounding, but results are still the same unfortunately.

Comment: @KlausD.  Yep, Python array is just a list, right?
But fundamentally, I'm not sure why they are producing such different results. Being that one works and the other doesnt't.

Comment: No, a `list` is not just an name for an `array`. The only things they have in common is that they use the `[ ]` syntax and that they are an ordered collection of items.

Comment: @KlausD. Sure, that makes sense, but do you see a reason why they would be behaving so differently in this context? when considering their differences...

Answer (score 1):

Add `left = left.copy()` at the start of `merge`, otherwise it's a view of `Array` so that writing into `Array` overwrites `left`.

(`right` is also a view, but that's ok since you're not overwriting it faster than you're reading it)

Comment: @Didier: Welcome to a confusing world: slices of python lists (which are implemented as vectors and use the Array syntax of other languages) duplicate the data whereas slices of numpy arrays, which use the same syntax are just views of said objects, sharing the data.